# How to react on vulnerability scanning?

Tags: security, best-practices

We noticed that our server is being scanned for standard vulnerabilities like publically exposed myphpadmin and other common security configuration mistakes / failures.
What is best locations to redirect such attackers to?
Options popping in my head:

- url with attacker self http://127.0.0.1/
- url with broadcast IP like http://255.255.255.255/

What else can be made except redirecting attacker?

Comment: A simple 404 is fine. You shouldn't have any administrative admin panels web accessible to the public anyway.

Comment: @DanielWidrick I do not have exposed admin panel without auth, question was about best reaction to try scan for various publically exposed files of comman admin panels, like myphpadmin. Formally I can collect IP addresses into some blacklist table and update related configs with cron job but I just looking for some best practices to follow before I implement some practice finally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return a 404 and move on.

Optionally, discipline bots that don't take the hint. Perhaps fail2ban style firewall rules that drop the connection.

Optionally, log such events centrally such as in a SIEM. Failed attempts are more noise than anything actionable, so don't consider those much of a threat.